# Div with full width on a page with horizontal scrollbars

Tags: css, html

I have a page with a header at the top and a table (rendered with asp.net gridview) below it that extends horizontally to the right of the visible area of the page, as in this pircture:

[image]

As you can see, the div (the blue header) only stetches up to the visible width of the page, not the whole width of the page that inlcudes the horizontal scrollbar.
Is it possible via css to stretch the div to include the full width of the page, including the sctrollbar?

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> .queryHeader { background-color: #003163; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial; Font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; border-style: double; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 2px; display: block; overflow: hidden; } </style>
```

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Aaahhh no Internet Explorer! Killl iitt!! Also: we'll need to see your HTML/CSS to better understand why the header div isn't stretching across the width of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Warp the div+Table with one div .

Comment: Sorry Royi, it still only renders the div at the page's visible width.